# Changes in vanilla JS code after using polyfill for Blob()

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Blob` and `FileReader` to process some image files originating from input elements. However, to be on the safe side, I've wrapped the entire operation within `if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {}`.

Now recently, I included a polyfill for `Blob` in my code, such that `BlobBuilder` is utilized in case `Blob` doesn't exist but `BlobBuilder` does (certain mobile browsers).

**My question is:** Since I've added the polyfill, is there anything I need to tweak in `if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {}`? E.g. should it be `if (window.FileReader && (window.Blob || window.BlobBuilder))` now?

My goal is to ensure my JS code is only called when `FileReader` and the polyfilled `Blob` both exist.

---

For reference, here's the polyfill for `Blob` I'm using:

```
Blob = (function() {
  var nativeBlob = Blob;

  // Add unprefixed slice() method.
  if (Blob.prototype.webkitSlice) {
    Blob.prototype.slice = Blob.prototype.webkitSlice;  
  }
  else if (Blob.prototype.mozSlice) {
    Blob.prototype.slice = Blob.prototype.mozSlice;  
  }

  // Temporarily replace Blob() constructor with one that checks support.
  return function(parts, properties) {
    try {
      // Restore native Blob() constructor, so this check is only evaluated once.
      Blob = nativeBlob;
      return new Blob(parts || [], properties || {});
    }
    catch (e) {
      // If construction fails provide one that uses BlobBuilder.
      Blob = function (parts, properties) {
        var bb = new (WebKitBlobBuilder || MozBlobBuilder), i;
        for (i in parts) {
          bb.append(parts[i]);
        }
        return bb.getBlob(properties && properties.type ? properties.type : undefined);
      };
    }        
  };
}());
```

If a seasoned dev has advice regarding tweaking this polyfill, I'm open to that as well. Thanks in advance.

*Note: let's stick to pure JS for the scope of this question. I'm a server-side dev who's a JS newbie. I want to learn vanilla JS fundamentals before moving on to JQuery.*

Comment: They're called polyfills because they fill in for the missing functionality the browser does not provide. So, `window.Blob` gets routed to your polyfill.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Oh okay. The fact that we're using dot notation on `window` to invoke `Blob` threw me off. I was thinking some kind of a default/native `Blob` object would be called, and not the polyfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that both `FileReader` and `Blob` exist then it's accurate to do this:

```
if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So although the polyfill `Blob` uses `WebKitBlobBuilder || MozBlobBuilder` as well, I don't need to test for that?

Comment: You can check for those too.